# How to allow a user with some role to let people to register their new accounts in drupal 7?

Tags: users

Is it possible to let a user with some role (not an admin) that will decide if somebody can register in drupal?

I know there is an option in admin menu

> Configuration->Account settings Option: Registration and cancellation Who can
>   register accounts?

Is there any other option to do it like a module that user has a permission to switch on or off registration new users?

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 7 you can use [Administer Users by Role](https://drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole) module

> **Administer Users by Role** : This module allows site builders to set up fine-grained permissions for allowing users to edit and delete other users — more specific than Drupal Core's all-or-nothing 'administer users' permission. It also provides and enforces a 'create users' permission.

Reference:

- [Create role for changing user accounts and not admins](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41773/create-role-for-changing-user-accounts-and-not-admins)

Answer (score 0):

First create a new role (e.g. "User admin") and give that user the permission: "Administer users".  That gives whoaver has that role the approve new registrations (which is what you want).

However, this permission is indeed a dangerous permission to give, because anyone that holds it can assign new roles to any user (including self), so there is nothing to stop that user from promoting self to the full admin role (this *not* what you want).

To fix this, add the [User protect](https://drupal.org/project/userprotect) module.  This lets you protect against unwanted privilege escalation.